# JPA/Hibernate - LocalDate is being converted to System Time Zone

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a TIME column in a MySQL database, and in my JPA Entity I have a property that looks like this:

```
@Column(name="appointment_time")
LocalTime time;
```

The System Default ZoneId in java is UTC; however, when I access the `time` field on the entity, it seems to be automatically converting the time to UTC which does not match what is actually in the database. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: I do not see any mentions about time zone in the MySQL [TIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html) type description.

Comment: What will you see after running the following sql: `SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone, @@SESSION.time_zone;` ? (see [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html))